# Is there a relatively robust way to detect if the current script is running as PYTHONSTARTUP?

Tags: python

Is there any relatively robust way to check if the currently running script is being automatically invoked as the `PYTHONSTARTUP` script rather than as a normal Python program?

The best method I know of is `os.getenv('PYTHONSTARTUP') != __file__`, but that relies on `PYTHONSTARTUP` containing the exact same path as `__file__`, which I don't think is necessarily the case on all platforms.

Comment: I would guess normalizing file (sorry, no formatting) should work. Eg os.abspath.

Comment: On my system, `sys.argv` is set to `['']` when python is started in interactive mode. Not sure how reliable that is, though.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I'm not trying to detect interactive mode though (?)

Comment: @deets: Well for one thing if the path changes in between for whatever reason then that'll be a problem... and then I don't know if relative paths might cause problems either. Really I don't think the solution should use a path at all.

Comment: AFAIK the PYTHONSTARTUP file is only executed if python is started in interactive mode. If you execute a file or command, even the `-i` flag won't read the PYTHONSTARTUP file. So I'm fairly sure starting python as `python` (with no arguments) is the only way to execute that file.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Ohh right I forgot! Interesting, thanks, I'll try that out!

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Nope, try `python -i -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)"`

Comment: @Mehrdad That doesn't execute the PYTHONSTARTUP file though.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Oops, you're right, I didn't realize! However it seems this one does: `python -i -`

Comment: Hmm, you're right. But the idea still works, I think. If `sys.argv` is either `['']` or `['-']`, you know PYTHONSTARTUP is executed.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I think you mean `sys.argv[1]` has to be `''` or `'-'`, since otherwise that would still break. Hmm, maybe that would work...?

Comment: @Mehrdad how is the path supposed to change in between? If you start a process, the environment variables are captured, and not subject to later changes. And I addressed the relative path question.

Comment: @deets: If you use `os.abspath` that will have to access the file system, which may no longer look like the way it did when the program started. If nothing else, it might just fail if the file has been moved.

Comment: @Mehrdad erm. sure. you can  also delete your python installation during the interpreter run, or otherwise poke holes. If guarding against meteor showers is your goal, this will become complicated. But for the actual case you are wrong. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/macpath.py#L186 shows that this is just about the current working directory, which again is a process global variable that has nothing to do with the real FS.